# Why doesn't my DOM get updated when I change the HTML with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<div id="info-message"></div>
```

I am changing the text in between the DIVs like this:

```
$('#info-message').html = "xxx";
```

However even though I can step through this in the firebug debugger I don't see any change on the screen and nothing is added when I look with firebug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is a method, you need to call it like one:

```
$('#info-message').html("xxx");
```

Currently, you are setting the `html` property of the jQuery object to the string "xxx".

Answer (score 2):

The correct usage of the `html()` jQuery method is:

```
$('#info-message').html("xxx");
```

And in case you wanted to retrieve the html of an element:

```
$('#info-message').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#info-message').html('xxx')
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use `html()` method:

```
$('#info-message').html("xxx");
```

and if you want to append an element and work with its DOM you can use the following:

```
var contentDiv = $('<div class="content">xxx</div>');
$('#info-message').append(contentDiv);

contentDiv.css('color', 'red');
```